# Changing value of one element inside List from True to False

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently struggling with trying to change an element value inside my nested List.

> UserRepository

`List<User> findByUsernameAndIsActiveTrue(String username);`

> User Entity

```
public class User {
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id_user")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
private long id;
@NotNull
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@NotNull
@Email
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@Column(name = "age")
private int age;
@Column(name = "address")
private String address;
@NotNull
@Column(name = "status")
private Boolean isActive;
```

> UserService

```
    boolean deleteUser(String username);
```

I'm trying to change the value of the isActive to false so it is counted as a soft delete, but I don't know how the code works in the ServiceImpl. Do I need to stream map the value inside? Since I'm going to use save later, does that mean if the other elements don't have any value inputted it will be null?

Comment: I think that you need to do two things: first, locate the specific user you want to change in the list of users. Then, change it and save only that entity to the repository.

Comment: I actually have the code in my UserServiceImpl to find based on the Username, but after that I don't know how to point to the specific element than I want to change.

`@Override
    public boolean deleteUser(String username) {
        userRepository.findByUsernameAndIsActiveTrue(username);
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to stream map the value inside?

Simply get the users that you want to delete using `UserRepository`, then set their `active` property to false.

> Since I'm going to use save later, does that mean if the other
>   elements don't have any value inputted it will be null?

No need to call `save` explicitly. Just let the transaction commit and it will figure out what you changed and automatically update these changes to DB when the transaction commit.

After getting the users to be deleted from UserRepository , they are already initialised with the value that are the same as DB record. The properties values will not be null if the related DB column is not null. Just make sure you don't change the properties that you don't intended to update.

The `ServiceImpl` will look like :

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl {

  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Transactional
  public boolean deleteUser(String username){
     List<User> users =  userRepository.findByUsernameAndIsActiveTrue(username);
     for(User user : users){
         user.isActive(false);       
    }
  }
}
```

Also make sure you enable `@Transactional` or equivalent for `deleteUser()`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it easier to do it this way. I was thinking if I have to map it then making it to temp and then replace it.

Comment: Is there actually any way to do it with JPA Repository .save? 
I wanted to try make the mockito for testing purpose later.

Comment: You can still call save , it will not have error in your case , but it is useless and it is not required to call it. For testing , I will directly test that user 's  active flag 
 is really changed to false instead .